# Xdebug doesnt work on docker on execute file from console

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I've configured a php and nginx containers that works, and xdebug stop on the breakpoints but only form browser request not from console this is the config that I have used, do I missed something to make xdebug works on console?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  web-server:
    container_name: web-server-container
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./public:/appdata/www/public
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - docker-network

  php:
    container_name: php-container
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./:/appdata/www
    env_file:
      - .env
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: "develop,debug"
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "client_host=host.docker.internal start_with_request=yes"
    networks:
      - docker-network

networks:
  docker-network:
    external: true
```

ngingx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /appdata/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass  php-container:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/prueba_nginx_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/prueba_nginx_access.log;
}
```

php Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.3.3-fpm

# Install packages and PHP extensions
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git acl openssl openssh-client wget zip vim librabbitmq-dev libssh-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libpng-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev libxml2-dev libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_mysql zip gd soap bcmath sockets \
    && pecl install xdebug amqp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 05-opcache.ini opcache xdebug amqp

# Install and update composer
RUN curl https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer
RUN composer self-update

# Install PHP-CS-FIXER
RUN wget https://cs.symfony.com/download/php-cs-fixer-v2.phar -O php-cs-fixer
RUN chmod a+x php-cs-fixer
RUN mv php-cs-fixer /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer

RUN mkdir -p /appdata/www

# Config XDEBUG
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

WORKDIR /appdata/www
```

and xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.mode=debug,coverage
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

and this is the launh.json config form vscode

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/appdata/www": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 0,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
        ],
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
            "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
            "-S",
            "localhost:0"
        ],
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
            "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Check where the PHP CLI is getting its `php.ini` from and then make sure you added the XDEBUG config to that one. `>php --ini` and look at the `php.ini` file mentioned in the output

Comment: How do you determine it doesn't work from console? What precisely are you doing? Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt because I execute a php file from console and it doesn't stop on breakpoints

Comment: I'm not sure what I have to check on the php.ini file @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well, if it's that simple, [edit] your Q to include that detail. Seriously, there are multiple ways I could imagine, but guessing is bad.

Comment: _because I execute a php file from console and it doesn't stop on breakpoints_ So how are you setting breakpoint when you run from the CLI.  [Without an IDE or using the dbgp client](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpClient) you have no way of setting a breakpoint

Comment: I set the breakpoint on vscode, using php-apache container it works but not using a container for php and a container for nginx @RiggsFolly

Comment: That would have been useful information to have put into the original question